# Angular Validation: Rollback ngModel.$modelValue update?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written an async validator. It calls a remote endpoint and checks if my field is unique or not. Remote endpoint is supposed to return **true** if it is unique and **false** otherwise. My validator:

```
    module.directive('shouldBeUnique', ['$parse', '$timeout', '$http', '$q', function ($parse, $timeout, $http, $q) {
    return {
        // restrict to an attribute type.
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            getEndPoint: '&'
        },
        priority: 1,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            function isUnique(value) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('shouldBeUnique', false);
                });

                //Cancels any ongoing http request
                if(scope.canceler) {
                    scope.canceler.resolve();
                }

                if(!value) {
                    return;
                }

                ngModel.validationInProgress = true;
                var canceler = scope.canceler = $q.defer();
                var endpointDetails = scope.getEndPoint();
                var params = {};
                params[endpointDetails.paramName] = value;
                var request = $http({
                    url: endpointDetails.url,
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: params,
                    timeout: canceler.promise
                });

                request.success(function(data) {
                    var valid = false;
                    if(data === 'true') {
                        valid = true;
                    }

                    ngModel.$setValidity('shouldBeUnique', valid);
                    ngModel.validationInProgress = false;
                });

                request.error(function() {
                    ngModel.validationInProgress = false;
                });
            }

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                isUnique(value);
                return value;
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('shouldBeUnique', true);
                ngModel.$dirty = true;
                if(ngModel.$valid) {
                    isUnique(value);
                }

                return value;
            });
        }
    };
}]);`
```

My validator works fine. The way it works is it will intially `setValidity` to true so that modelValue gets updated. And then actual validity is checked asynchronously and `ngModel.setValidity` is called accordingly.

The only problem I'm facing here is `ngModel.$modelValue` gets updated before the validity is checked so it can have invalid data. Is there a way to rollback commit to `modelValue`?

I could find `$rollbackViewValue` but nothing for model. Or is there any way I can postpone `ngModel.$modelValue` update upto the time when async call completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve the issue. When async call is in progress, commit a temp value, something like "VALIDATION_PENDING" and when the validation completes, do ngModel.$commitViewValue(true). I'm passing true to trigger the parser again. Your parser should handle the case when ngModel.$modelValue === 'VALIDATION_PENDING'. In this case don't make the async call, simply return the $viewValue from Parser.

Code:

```
module.directive('shouldBeUnique', ['$parse', '$timeout', '$http', '$q', 'VALIDATION_PENDING', function ($parse, $timeout, $http, $q, VALIDATION_PENDING) {
    return {
        // restrict to an attribute type.
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            getEndPoint: '&'
        },
        priority: 1,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var lastValidationStatus;

            function isUnique(value) {
                //Cancels any ongoing http request
                if(scope.canceler) {
                    scope.canceler.resolve();
                }

                var canceler = scope.canceler = $q.defer();
                var endpointDetails = scope.getEndPoint();
                var params = {};
                params[endpointDetails.paramName] = value;
                var httpDeferred = $http({
                    url: endpointDetails.url,
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: params,
                    timeout: canceler.promise
                });

                ngModel.validationInProgress = true;
                return httpDeferred;
            }

            function setValidity(httpDeferred) {
                httpDeferred.success(function(data) {
                    lastValidationStatus = false;
                    if(data === 'true') {
                        lastValidationStatus = true;
                    }

                    ngModel.validationInProgress = false;
                    ngModel.$commitViewValue(true);
                });

                httpDeferred.error(function() {
                    ngModel.validationInProgress = false;
                });
            }

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                if(value) {
                    var httpDeferred = isUnique(value);
                    setValidity(httpDeferred);
                }
                return value;
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('shouldBeUnique', true);

                if(ngModel.$valid) {
                    var httpDeferred;

                    if (ngModel.$modelValue === VALIDATION_PENDING && !ngModel.validationInProgress) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            ngModel.$setValidity('shouldBeUnique', lastValidationStatus);
                        });
                        if (lastValidationStatus) {
                            return value;
                        }
                        return undefined;
                    }
                    else {
                        httpDeferred = isUnique(value);
                        setValidity(httpDeferred);
                        return VALIDATION_PENDING;
                    }
                }

                return undefined;
            });
        }
    };
}]);

module.constant('VALIDATION_PENDING', '###REMOTE_VALIDATION_IN_PROGRESS###');
```

Comment: @ryeballar :Is is still very complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating the way you handle your validation. You can use ngModel's `$viewChangeListeners` callback array to add your validation. This array of callbacks are triggered whenever there are changes in your input, this is where the `ngChange` directive callbacks are registered.

The solution can be something like this, (you can check my example in this **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/505EQeeBtf2vbZGIIe2l?p=preview)**):

```
  directive('uniqueData', function($http, $q, $timeout) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$setValidity('uniqueData', true); // default

        var canceller,
          request = function() {

            // set validity to true whenever changes are made
            ngModel.$setValidity('uniqueData', true);

            if(canceller)
              canceller.resolve();

            canceller = $q.defer();

            ngModel.isInProgress = true;

            // you can remove the timeout
            // it only simulates a timed request
            $timeout(function() {

              $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'users.json',
                timeout: canceller.promise
              }).success(function(data) {
                for(var index in data) {
                  var user = data[index];
                  if(user.username == ngModel.$modelValue) {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('uniqueData', false);
                    break;
                  }
                }
              })['finally'](function() {
                ngModel.isInProgress = false;
              });

            }, 2000);
          };

        ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(request);

      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Even in your solution, ngModel.$modelValue gets updated with a username which is already occupied. I don't want my $modelValue to have invalid data. How do I prevent that?